# Skyrim won't let me use the dragon souls I have to unlock shouts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know you have to find the shout and absorb the dragon soul to make the shout work...and for every word the shout has you need the same about of dragon souls. I have 17 dragon souls so the amount of souls is not a problem. And I have seven shouts to unlock.

My problem is when i try to unlock the shout it says "Dragon Souls are required to unlock shouts." even though i have 17 dragon souls.

help??

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the proper button for "Unlock"?  I found myself often accidentally hitting the "Equip" button instead.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.  The linked question is from someone originally ignorant of the fact that you have to take action, other than simply absorbing the soul, to unlock shouts.  This question is about troubleshooting failure of that action.